# How i can parse next string:

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have next string and tring to get only Site Name string from each array

```
let text = '[[{"value":"Site Name"}]]AAAAAAAA[[{"value":"Site Name"}]]BBBB'
```

So, it would be looking like this :

Site NameAAAAAAAASite NameBBBB

I've tried something like

```
text.replace(/(\[[{"value":")(\w+)(\"}]])/g, '$2'))
```

but it didn't work

Pls help

Comment: Do you mean you have `let text = '[[{"value":"Site Name"}]]AAAAAAAA[[{"value":"Site Name"}]]BBBB'`? If yes, try `text.match(/(?<=\[\[{"value":")[^"]*/g)`

Comment: Your `text` variable isn't valid. Should it be a string? An array?

Comment: You say "...from each array" but you don't have any arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
/\[{2}{"value":"(.*?)"/g
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/u3d2ON/1).
**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[{2}                    '[' (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  {"value":"               '{"value":"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
let text = '[[{"value":"Site Name"}]]AAAAAAAA[[{"value":"Site Name"}]]BBBB'
const matches = text.matchAll(/\[{2}{"value":"(.*?)"/g)
console.log( Array.from(matches, z => z[1]) )
```